# python-glpk + module object has no attribute tabversian + linux

Tags: python, linux, glpk

I've just installed Python-GLPK on my Linux (it's Linux mint 18 and I am using it on oracle virtual box while my original one is windows 10, I am completely new with Linux and glpk)
I used these 3 command to install python-GLPK :

sudo apt-get install python-glpk
sudo apt-get install libglpk-dev
sudo apt-get install glpk-utils

I wrote a simple .py file "import glpk" and run it using $ python to test but this is my error :
AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute '_tabversian'
What did i missed?

Thank you very much. i appreciate your help